# How do I vertically center a UIImageView in a UIScrollView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that puts a `UIImageView` inside a `UIView` wrapper that is then put into a `UIScrollView`. I need the image to be completely zoomed out and centered vertically.

The View Controller is instantiated and presented within a 600x600 `UIPopoverController`.

This is the code I have for the view controller:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:self.image];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];



    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;

    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];


    [self.containerView addSubview:imageView];

    [scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .4;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:.4];


    self.view = scrollView;

}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.containerView;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of things to center it, but it always appears at the top of the scroll view.

Comment: Have you checked Autolayout option during start of the project?

Answer (score 0):

use ContentSize and ContentOffSet for UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout and center the container view in the scrollview..  Use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html  this link if u need help with autolayouts..